# "Duplicate symbol" with anything less than "-O2"

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, clang, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to compile a large source tree with clang whose default settings for debug mode until now where `-O3`. This unfortunately optimizes away a lot of the crucial debug info, but when I set the Optimization level in xcode to anything less than `-O2`, say `-O0`, The linker starts giving duplicate symbol errors.

```
duplicate symbol __Z7CONTROLSs12CONTROL_TYPEff in:
    /Users/... /main.o
    /Users/... /ofxCocoa.o
    ...
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

So Two questions:

1. Why, in theory, should optimization levels change the linker output?
2. Does anyone have any idea how I can remedy this problem? I can't really post the code, but helpful guesses will be gladly accepted.

Comment: lower optimization levels prevent the compiler from doing various static analysis on the code, such as perhaps realizing that some code blocks are unreachable. If you define multiple vars, but some are inside unreachable blocks, then those blocks can be optimized away and prevent the dupe identifier errors. They're still dupes in the code, but can't be in an execution environment.

Comment: Another related possibility is that whole functions are getting optimized away at -O3, if they're never called or are just stubs.  Then, at -O0 they suddenly are present, but conflict with other symbols in other modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> duplicate symbol __Z7CONTROLSs12CONTROL_TYPEff

This usually happens when you define an inline function in a header file, but neglect to declare it with `inline` keyword.

> Why, in theory, should optimization levels change the linker output?

When you build with optimization, the compiler actually *does* inline the function, and doesn't emit "out of line" definition, resulting in successful link.

You can verify this by running `nm main.o | grep __Z7CONTROLSs12CONTROL_TYPEff` -- with optimization on, I expect no output.

> how I can remedy this problem

Add missing `inline`, or move the definition of the function out of header file, and into a regular C++ source.